# Converting json that changes per request

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im currently making my own cryptocurrency tracker for myself as a bit of fun but im stuck a bit. The service im using is:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=

I own 3 cryptocurrencies that use certain codes to pull data from the api, heres an example request:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,LKK,BTC&tsyms=ETH,LKK,BTC

which would return:

```
 {
"ETH": {
    "BTC": 0.04948,
    "LKK": 876.08,
    "ETH": 1
},
"LKK": {
    "BTC": 0.00005356,
    "LKK": 1,
    "ETH": 0.001141
},
"BTC": {
    "BTC": 1,
    "LKK": 18671.99,
    "ETH": 20.21
    }
}
```

Using newtonsoft.json, I usually convert the json to an object but the more currencies I buy in the future, the classes would have to be created dynamically because the header of each result is the currency name? how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want dictionary of dictionaries:

```
var json = "{\r\n\"ETH\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 0.04948,\r\n    \"LKK\": 876.08,\r\n    \"ETH\": 1\r\n},\r\n\"LKK\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 0.00005356,\r\n    \"LKK\": 1,\r\n    \"ETH\": 0.001141\r\n},\r\n\"BTC\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 1,\r\n    \"LKK\": 18671.99,\r\n    \"ETH\": 20.21\r\n    }\r\n}";
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.
    DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,float>>>(json);
```

Results in

```
ETH 
     BTC 0.04948 
     LKK 876.08 
     ETH 1 
LKK 
     BTC 5.356E-05 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your json datafeed to

```
Dictionary<string, CurrencyDescriptor>
```

Where CurrencyDescriptor is a class that may look like this:

```
public class CurrencyDescriptor
{
    public double BTC;
    public double LKK;
    public double ETH;
}
```

Then you deserialize you json string like this:

```
var Dictionary<string, CurrencyDescriptor> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CurrencyDescriptor>>(json);
```

Adding new currency would only require adding new field to CurrencyDescriptor class.

Comment: I will want this to run through a ui so i couldnt keep adding fields.

Comment: Well, then suggestion of @alexei-levenkov with deserialization to dictionary of dictionaries should work. It's dynamic enough

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot deserialize directly to predefined class (aside from various forms of dictionaries), it's still better to use some type for your data, for example:

```
public class CurrencyRate {
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like this:

```
string test = "{\r\n\"ETH\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 0.04948,\r\n    \"LKK\": 876.08,\r\n    \"ETH\": 1\r\n},\r\n\"LKK\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 0.00005356,\r\n    \"LKK\": 1,\r\n    \"ETH\": 0.001141\r\n},\r\n\"BTC\": {\r\n    \"BTC\": 1,\r\n    \"LKK\": 18671.99,\r\n    \"ETH\": 20.21\r\n    }\r\n}";            
var result = JsonConvert.
   DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>>(test);
var rates = result.SelectMany(
    from => from.Value.Select(
    to => new CurrencyRate{ From = from.Key, To = to.Key, Rate = to.Value })
).ToList();
```

In more complicated cases you can deserialize to raw `JObject` and work with that:

```
var result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test);
```

You can also work with that using dynamic:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test);
decimal btcToEth = result.ETH.BTC;
```